printk() output weird value
When modifying a Linux net interface driver, I use printk() to print the system time in driver probe function. But its output is weird, code snippet like this:
void *axienet_ptp_timer_probe(void __iomem *base, struct platform_device *pdev)
{
  ...
  ts = ktime_to_timespec64(ktime_get_real());
  printk(KERN_ERR "probe:sec:%ld,nsec:%ld\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
  pr_debug("%s: sec: %ld nsec: %ld\n", __func__, ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
  ...
}

when kernel boots, output message looks like this:
probe:sec:0,nsec:2
axienet_ptp_timer_probe: sec: 2 nsec: 0

Why do the printk() and pr_debug() have different output?
For testing printk(), I also add more parameter to it:
int test = 12;
...
ts = ktime_to_timespec64(ktime_get_real());
printk(KERN_ERR "probe:sec:%ld,nsec:%ld,test:%ld\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec, test);
pr_debug("%s: sec: %ld nsec: %ld\n", __func__, ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);

output:
probe:sec:0,nsec:2,test:0
axienet_ptp_timer_probe: sec: 2 nsec: 0

As Tsyvarev said,I changed specifier "%ld" to "%lld".I got same output
void *axienet_ptp_timer_probe(void __iomem *base, struct platform_device *pdev)
{
  ...
  ts = ktime_to_timespec64(ktime_get_real());
  printk(KERN_ERR "probe:sec:%lld,nsec:%ld\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
  pr_debug("%s: sec: %lld nsec: %ld\n", __func__, ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
  ...
}

output:
probe:sec:2,nsec:482266037
axienet_ptp_timer_probe: sec: 2 nsec: 482266037


Are your system is 32-bit or 64-bit? Specifier "%ld" corresponds to the type long, which is 32-bit on 32-bit machine. But ts.tv_sec is 64-bit. See also that question about proper format specifier for 64-bit values.

i thought it would auto cast ,if the format specifier and parameter had different type.

A format specifier is not a type. All the compiler knows is that printk is a function with variable number of parameters and that ts.tv_sec is one of its parameters. (Well, modern compilers could check specifiers in a printk format string. The purpose of this check is to emit a warning in case of inconsistency between actual types of arguments and types expected by the specifiers. But a specifier never affects the object code generated by the compiler.)
